# Does a heaviside step function exist?

Tags: python, matlab

Is there a [heaviside](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) function in Python similar to that of MATLAB's [`heaviside`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/heaviside.html)?

I am struggling to find one.

Comment: Numpy has a [heaviside](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.heaviside.html) function.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

If you are using numpy version 1.13.0 or later, you can use `numpy.heaviside`:

```
In [61]: x
Out[61]: array([-2. , -1.5, -1. , -0.5,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ])

In [62]: np.heaviside(x, 0.5)
Out[62]: array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ])
```

With older versions of numpy you can implement it as `0.5 * (numpy.sign(x) + 1)`

```
In [65]: 0.5 * (numpy.sign(x) + 1)
Out[65]: array([ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ,  1. ])
```

Answer (score 23):

Probably the simplest method is just

```
def step(x):
    return 1 * (x > 0)
```

This works for both single numbers and numpy arrays, returns integers, and is zero for x = 0. The last criteria may be preferable over `step(0) => 0.5` in certain circumstances.

Comment: @becko Definitely more readable, but it won't work on numpy arrays. If you try it you'll get `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`. And it's probably less readable than `return 1 if x > 0 else 0`, which is almost identical to what you have here.

Comment: Right, you had me with the Numpy arrays

Answer (score 13):

It's part of [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/0.6.7/modules/functions.html#heaviside), which you can install with `pip install sympy`

From the docs:

```
class sympy.functions.special.delta_functions.Heaviside


Heaviside Piecewise function. Heaviside function has the following properties: 

1) diff(Heaviside(x),x) = DiracDelta(x)    ( 0, if x<0 )
2) Heaviside(x) = < [*] 1/2 if x==0        ( 1, if x>0 )
```

You would use it like this:

```
In [1]: from sympy.functions.special.delta_functions import Heaviside

In [2]: Heaviside(1)
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: Heaviside(0)
Out[3]: 1/2

In [4]: Heaviside(-1)
Out[4]: 0
```

You could also write your own:

```
heaviside = lambda x: 0.5 if x == 0 else 0 if x < 0 else 1
```

Although that may not meet your needs if you require a symbolic variable.

Answer (score 6):

As of numpy 1.13, it is `numpy.heaviside`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if it's there out-of-the-box, but you can always write one:

```
def heaviside(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 0.5

    return 0 if x < 0 else 1
```

Comment: Or just `return 0.5 if x == 0 else 0 if x < 0 else 1`.

Comment: It's certainly shorter, but I prefer not nesting `if..else` statements if it can be avoided. It's a matter of style I guess. :)

Comment: I recently objected to someone nesting something like this three levels deep.  But I also noticed that Python's version of the conditional expression nests much better than most.

Comment: This definition works fine for my needs. Thank you @netcoder and to everybody else who has contributed.

Comment: Watch your use of constants 0, you may want to use 0.0 and 1.0 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the best way getting things done... but here is function  that I hacked up.

```
def u(t):
    unit_step = numpy.arange(t.shape[0])
    lcv = numpy.arange(t.shape[0])
        for place in lcv:
            if t[place] == 0:
               unit_step[place] = .5
            elif t[place] > 0:
               unit_step[place] = 1
            elif t[place] < 0:
    unit_step[place] = 0
    return unit_step
```

[image: Ipython Plot with Pylab and NumPy]

Answer (score 1):

```
def heaviside(xx):
    return numpy.where(xx <= 0, 0.0, 1.0) + numpy.where(xx == 0.0, 0.5, 0.0)
```

Or, if `numpy.where` is too slow:

```
def heaviside(xx):
    yy = numpy.ones_like(xx)
    yy[xx < 0.0] = 0.0
    yy[xx == 0.0] = 0.5
    return yy
```

The following timings are with numpy 1.8.2; some optimisations were made in numpy 1.9.0, so try this yourself:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import numpy
>>> array = numpy.arange(10) - 5
>>> def one():
...  return numpy.where(array <= 0, 0.0, 1.0) + numpy.where(array == 0.0, 0.5, 0.0)
... 
>>> def two():
...  yy = numpy.ones_like(array)
...  yy[array < 0] = 0.0
...  yy[array == 0] = 0.5
...  return yy
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(one, number=100000)
3.026144027709961
>>> timeit.timeit(two, number=100000)
1.5265140533447266
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.8.2'
```

On a different machine, with a different numpy:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(one, number=100000)
0.5119631290435791
>>> timeit.timeit(two, number=100000)
0.5458788871765137
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.11.1'
>>> def three():
...  return 0.5*(numpy.sign(array) + 1)
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(three, number=100000)
0.313539981842041
```

Comment: Needs a xx = np.asarray() to work with any sequence and then is 3x as slow as the accepted answer. But it's also a workable solution.

Comment: Thanks, @orbeckst, for the push to optimise my solution, which I've done.  Note also that with a modern numpy, it's only about 60% slower.

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution:

```
import numpy as np
amplitudes = np.array([1*(x >= 0) for x in range(-5,6)])
```